# Misaligned listview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm making a football league app, and i need to show the classification.
I'm trying to show a header that indicates what represents each field and a listview with the teams below.
I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to fill the list, but if the values have a different number of digits the list is misaligned. ¿How can i align it or at least add a 0 before the one-digit numbers with the adapter?

The soure code of the fragment and the xml:

ClassificacioFragment.java:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] from = { EquipsContract.EquipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOM,
                EquipsContract.EquipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_VICTORIES, EquipsContract.EquipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DERROTES,
                EquipsContract.EquipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EMPATS,  EquipsContract.EquipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PUNTS};
        int[] to = {R.id.item_nom, R.id.item_victories, R.id.item_derrotes, R.id.item_empats, R.id.item_punts};
        View rootview =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classificacio, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.classificacio);
        listView.invalidateViews();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(rootview.getContext(), R.layout.equip_row,
                DBHandler.getDbInstance(getContext()).cursorClassificacio(), from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String size = Integer.toString(DBHandler.getDbInstance(getContext()).getAllEquips().size());
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        return rootview;
    }
```

fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="idi.francesc.footballleague.ClassificacioFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_classificacio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/header_equip"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/header_victories"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/header_d"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_d"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/header_derrotes"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/header_e"
                android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/header_empats"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/header_p"
                android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/header_punts"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/classificacio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_classificacio">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Listview Row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_nom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="F.C. Barcelona"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:id="@+id/item_victories"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_derrotes"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:id="@+id/item_derrotes"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_empats"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:id="@+id/item_empats"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="30"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_punts"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_punts"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="40"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

thanks.

Comment: you need to use `layout_weight` for this. this misalignment is due to different sizes of your first textview due to width set to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your `ListView` Row to use `LinearLayout` with `weight` parameters. It's more efficient and prevents issues with `TextView`'s floating width.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="9">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_nom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="F.C. Barcelona"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/item_victories"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="10"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/item_derrotes"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="20"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/item_empats"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="30"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/item_punts"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="40"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked after setting the android:layout_width of the first TextView to 0.

Comment: Sure, it should be 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first all of your text in the TextView must be center aligned.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Then, pogramatically you should find the largest TextView and set the width of each other TextView in that row.

Or you use TableLayout ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for appending 0 with numbers less than 10.

```
public String appendZero(int input) {
   if (input >= 10) {
    return String.valueOf(input);
   } else {
    return "0" + String.valueOf(input);
   }
}
```

While setting the text, call like this :

```
item_victories.setText(appendZero(victory_count.get(position)));
```

Hope this one will works for you.